# Indicate comments belonging to the original poster in the android app

Tags: feature-request, comments, android-app

On the website we get an indication when it's the poster that's commenting. Can we have the same functionality for the android app; some kind of indication when the comment belongs to the poster.

Comment: I am the original poster and this is my comment!

Comment: I am not the original poster and this is not my comment!