# Highlight OP's comments on the Android mobile app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, android-app

On the websites, whenever the OP comments on an answer, or on his question, his name is highlighted. This is a handy feature because you can easily tell whether the comment is from the OP or not.

But on the Android mobile app (don't know about iOS),  this feature is not there. Can we have it please!?

[image: name highlighting on web]

[image: no highlight on Android app :(]

Comment: Just made a feature request for iOS. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242711/highlight-ops-comments-in-ios-app?lq=1

Comment: I thought this was already asked before, but surprisingly I couldn't find any dupe of it! +1. **Edit:** well, apparently it was already asked, but this post explains the issue better, so I flagged [that question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193602/241919) as a dupe of this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry it took *so* long to do this -- It was difficult to do with the separation of logic the app used to have so I punted it, but it ended up being really easy to do now after we've re-written a lot of the logic.

Here's what the indicator looks like as of version 1.0.59+:

[image]

Comment: that's great!!!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yep, I can do *ANYTHING*, done :)

Comment: If I might ask here, what about auto expanding comments when arriving from the inbox? Currently when there are few comments with "Show more comments" link, it won't auto expand, thus also no focus. :/