# Highlight OP's comments in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, ios-app

Just the iOS version of the Android app question: [Highlight OP's comments on the Android mobile app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242706/259693)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done! Display names for OP's comments will now appear with a light blue background:

[image]

This will be available starting in Beta version 1.2.0.142.

Comment: iOS team won! :)