# Highlight OP in comments

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Is it possible to highlight the OP's name in the comments in Android app?

[image]

Comment: Highlight in which way? This seems to be the case already...

Comment: @Werner it is not.

Comment: @nicael: The question is about the "OP's name in comments." And from the view I can see it is set in **bold** and most likely clickable. What other highlighting is meant here?

Comment: @Werner http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242706/can-we-highlight-the-ops-comments-on-the-android-mobile-app-please

Comment: @nicael: It's clear now, and also clearly a duplicate.

Comment: @Werner yep, and has 4 of 5 close votes already.

Comment: @nicael whoops. Didn't find that question :P